# Including JS plugin files directly in Github repository?

Tags: javascript, git, github, zip, slick.js

I am relatively new to using git and GitHub, and I am working on my personal website. I am using the JS plugin Slick, a responsive carousel feature. I downloaded all of the necessary files and stored them within my local repo. The size and content of the Slick zip folder is much larger than the files for my site at the moment, so when syncing with GitHub this makes my project appear as 75% Javascript, whereas the actual website is not.

Am I doing this correctly, storing the files for my JS plugin directly within my repository folder? Or should I be using some other method to implement Slick on my site? Or is this just something I should not be worried about? Thanks

Comment: You should be having Slick as a dependency, but if you're using Github Sites that may not be possible

Comment: You shouldn't be worried about that (useless) bar across the top of your GitHub repo. Ignore it.

Comment: @pfg I'm not using GH sites, just testing locally with xampp, pushing to GitHub, uploading to web host

Comment: @JDB noted, thanks. Just wondering if I was needlessly cluttering my repo and there was a better method of implementation I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Personally, I like having all of my dependencies in the repo. NPM is great [until it suddenly isn't](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/). If everything to build your project is in your repo, getting new devs setup and managing the complexity of shifting plugin versions is soooooo much easier. But to each his/her own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just using one library, manually storing it in your Git repo is fine. You'd have to manually update the files if a new version is released, but that's not a big deal for one library. (And you might not even care about updates to this library).

However if you're using more than one library, I'd highly recommend using Node Package Manager (NPM) and a build tool like Webpack.

Here's an article that introduces these tools (plus a few others): https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/what-are-npm-yarn-babel-and-webpack-and-how-to-properly-use-them-d835a758f987

Comment: Yes. This. I highly recommend being explicit about package version numbers, though, otherwise you can end up with inconsistent behavior across environments and hard to track down bugs.

Answer (score 0):

For using git, you should store your dependencies in a folder that is in your `.gitignore`. If you install [browserify](http://browserify.org) or another similar tool like webpack, you can use the [npm](https://npmjs.com) package manager to create a dependency list file with `npm init` that allows for easy package installation with `npm install` by anyone. You can install packages slick with `npm install --save`[`slick-carousel`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slick-carousel) and use them with `require()` in your main js file. Then, take your js file and run `browserify jsfile.js -o outputfile.js` and it will package your js and your dependencies together to be used by the browser

When uploading to your git repo, add a `.gitignore` like [this one for Node](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore). This prevents your dependencies from being uploaded to the repo and instead when someone wants to run your project, they must run `npm install` to get all the dependencies.

Browserify gives an output JS file you add to your web server, the name of this file should be put in your `.gitignore` as well. Your code is stored in the js file you pass to browserify and other people can still access it without the output file, but they need to run the browserify command to package your code.